# Why doesn't work sharing / in samba any more on my rpi?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, share, root, samba

Usually for my lab Setup of my raspberry pi, I create a share that Shares everything. I use the default smb.conf and append this:

```
[all]
comment = all
path = /
writeable = Yes
create mask = 0777
directory mask = 0777
browseable = Yes
public = Yes
guest ok = No
valid users = pi
```

After a recent update, I can still Access this share, however I can not go into any Directory there. I changed nothing else. All permissions are still the same.
I tried that on another pi and had the same effect. I confirmed that it worked before and doesn't after the update.
It still works if I share something else, for example /projects . Just / got this wired behaviour.
I also tried installing jessie lite and another sd Card and that one also has this effect. I didn't have this effect with 3.x kernel and wheezy.

Is there a way I can make this work again?

Also, I have an ubuntu 15.10 running and updated that and there, I can still share / without any problems.

Comment: Who downvoted this and why? I can't enhance the question that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get the downvotes, however after updating to a new version, my config works again. So it was a problem of a version in between.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't imagine that / would be owned by 'pi' and not 'root'.

Do you have a /home/pi directory? Can you access that?

Comment: I can access the pi home Directory share directly. However, from the / share, I can't go into any subdirectory, including /home/pi. This worked before the update.